# ROS2 custom message python import error

Tags: python, ros2, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
Deatails:
ROS Env

```
ROS_VERSION=2
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0
ROS_DISTRO=foxy
```

I created a custom message as follows in Custom.msg file

```
uint32 number
```

I have a publisher code with as follows

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

from std_msgs.msg import String

from ros_nodes import Custom


class MinimalPublisher(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('minimal_publisher')
        self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(String, 'topic', 10)
        timer_period = 0.5  # seconds
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)
        self.i = 0

    def timer_callback(self):
        #msg = String()
        msg = Custom()
        msg.number = self.i
        self.publisher_.publish(msg)
        self.get_logger().info('Publishing: "%s"' % msg.data)
        self.i += 1


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    minimal_publisher = MinimalPublisher()

    rclpy.spin(minimal_publisher)

    # Destroy the node explicitly
    # (optional - otherwise it will be done automatically
    # when the garbage collector destroys the node object)
    minimal_publisher.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When i try to run i am getting following error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Custom' from 'ros_nodes'
```

This error is not python import error but specific to that python is not able to import custo.msg
Am i doing something wrong. Can you guys share a sample project. As of now i am not using CMakeList or package.xml I don't think any of them are required. How do we use ros generate message to get the message imported. What is the right way to do with custom messages in python.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355444/ros2-custom-message-python-import-error/) by [Malz](https://answers.ros.org/users/53815/malz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

can you provide more details about where did you locate the `Custom.msg` ? Did you create a specific package for building your custom messages?

You can follow this [tutorial](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces/) in the official documentation.

Regards

---

Originally posted by [ahcorde](https://answers.ros.org/users/50386/ahcorde/) with karma: 421 on 2020-06-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Malz](https://answers.ros.org/users/53815/malz/) on 2020-07-05**:
https://github.com/malapatiravi/ros2_custom_msg
I was able to implement this. Please refer to the link above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is currently not possible in ROS2 to create a custom message type in a Python package:

https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces/#id4

You need to put your message in a separate C++ package.

---

Originally posted by [nsprague](https://answers.ros.org/users/2815/nsprague/) with karma: 228 on 2020-06-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1